# File template variable ${TIME}

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

In PHPStorm, the file template variable `${TIME}` renders as one hour ahead of my system time.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI - fixed my problem!  When I switched the time zone on my PC to Moscow, it picked up the time zone change after restarting PHPStorm.  Then I simply changed it back to Pacific Time Zone and now it's where it should be, showing system time.  I have a hunch this issue was related in part to daylight-savings settings, but in any case it's working now.